# Emacs org-mode latex - simply switch between pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex

Tags: emacs, org-mode, pdflatex, xelatex

Using `latexmk` I've tested the following setup

`(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("latexmk %f -output-directory=%o -%latex"))`

using the example below

```
#+TITLE: My Paper
#+AUTHOR: Jane Doe
#+DATE:
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setsansfont{Acme}

* Title
- Text
```

and it works for `xelatex` und `lualatex`, but not for `pdflatex` because `latexmk` fails with the option `-pdflatex`, which would require a string.

Is there any easy way to fix this issue? E.g. set `org-latex-pdf-process` based on a the selection of the `LATEX_COMPILER` using a hook?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution, which works for me

`(setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdflatex='%latex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -output-directory=%o %f"))`